# Purpose of --enable-gold when configuring gcc

Tags: gcc, gold-linker, gcc5

When building gcc 5.1 from source, the configure script lists the following option:

```
--enable-gold[=ARG]     build gold [ARG={default,yes,no}]
```

What does this mean? Is it telling gcc to use gold as the linker if gold is installed on the box ? If so, does it expect gold to be the default linker or should I point to gold via the

```
--with-ld=<path/to/linker>
```

option?

I could not find a reference to --enable-gold in the online gcc configure docs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GCC shares its top-level `configure` script with some other GNU projects, notably [Binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) and [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

`--enable-gold` is an option for Binutils, which says to build the [Gold linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(linker)) as well as the older BFD linker. The option has absolutely no effect when building GCC.